# Problem from I.N.Herstein (Linear transformation)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be such that for each i, 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{j} a_{ij}=1.
\end{equation*}
Prove that $1$ is characteristic root of A.

Generalisation: Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be such that for each i,
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{j} a_{ij}=n
\end{equation*}
where n is any integer then prove that n is characteristic root of A. Can we generalize it? give me some hint.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be $m\times m$ matrix such that sum of each row is equal to $n$, then consider
$$\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots &a_{1m}\cr a_{21}&a_{22}&\cdots &a_{2m} \cr \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \cr a_{m1}&a_{m2}&\cdots &a_{mm}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1\cr 1 \cr \vdots \cr 1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}+a_{12}+\cdots +a_{1m} \cr a_{21}+a_{22}+\cdots +a_{2m} \cr \vdots  \cr a_{m1}+a_{m2}+\cdots +a_{mm}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} n\cr n \cr \vdots \cr n \end{pmatrix}=n\begin{pmatrix} 1\cr 1 \cr \vdots \cr 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Clearly, $n$ is an eigenvalue of the given matrix $A$, hence it will be a root of characteristic polynomial.

**Note:** It should work for any number $n$, not necessarily integers.

Comment: What can we say about other characteristic root (with multiplicity)?

Comment: I don't know. 
But if we multiply one more vector $(1,-1,1,-1,\cdots, (-1)^{m+1})$ as following then for even order matrix $A$ with above property we get  zero

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&1&\cdots&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots  &a_{1m}\cr a_{21}&a_{22}&\cdots &a_{2m} \cr \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \cr a_{m1}&a_{m2}&\cdots &a_{mm}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1\cr 1 \cr \vdots \cr 1 \end{pmatrix}=0$$
Can it give some more information about the matrix $A$???

Answer (score 3):

Let $e=(1, 1, \cdots, 1)$. Then $Ae = (\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}) e$, if the sum $\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}$ is constant for all $i$.

Comment: What does $\;a_{ij}e\;$ means *inside* that sum? I think some care must be taken here.

Comment: @Timbuc I missed the bracket. Is it OK now?

Comment: I don't think so, as that'd mean that the sum in brackert **is** $\;A\;$ , which is not. What wrong with writing simply $$e=(1,1,...,1)\implies Ae=\begin{pmatrix}\sum_{j=1}^n a_{1j}\cdot1=1\\\ldots\\\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}\cdot1=1\\\ldots\\\sum_{j=1}^na_{nj}\cdot1=1\end{pmatrix}=e$$